# Adding a scope to user model with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a multi-tenant app using subdomains ala railscast #388. I am using devise for authentication so it added a different twist that's causing an issue. I am running into the following error when I try to add a new user with an email that is already built under a different subdomain(account):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RegistrationsController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("account_id", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Adding a new user works great if the email for the new user doesn't exist anywhere in the db so I'm assuming there is an issue with how I'm adding the scope to the email validation. I disabled the :validatable devise module and added the validations to my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable


  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  belongs_to :account


  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :account_id, :case_sensitive => false, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  validates_format_of :email, :with => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  validates_presence_of :password, :on=>:create
  validates_confirmation_of :password, :on=>:create
  validates_length_of :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true

  default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }

end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain
  has_many :clients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users
  cattr_accessor :current_id

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  around_filter :scope_current_account

private

  def current_account
    Account.find_by_subdomain! request.subdomain
  end
  helper_method :current_account

  def scope_current_account
    Account.current_id = current_account.id
    yield
  ensure
    Account.current_id = nil
  end

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a migration that removes the unique constraint on the "index_users_on_email" index added by Devise. Perhaps as such:

```
def up
  remove_index :users, :name => 'index_users_on_email'
  add_index :users, :email, :unique => false
end

def down
  remove_index :users, :name => 'index_users_on_email'
  add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
end
```

Comment: Or even better add the following index: add_index :users, [:account_id, :email], :unique => true